# UniFi and pfSense IPSec VPN not passing traffic

Tags: vpn, ipsec, pfsense, site-to-site-vpn, unifi

I have a IPSec VPN running between two sites. Site A is pfSense and site B is a UniFi Security Gateway. I have got the VPN established but I cant ping anything in either direction on the network. Any idas why this might be? Here are some screenshots -

[image: IPSec Status from pfSense]

*The status is connected*

[image: UniFi VPN Status]

*The status is connected*

[image: IPSec Config from UniFi]

*IPSec configuration from the UniFi controller*

[image: IPSec Config pfSense]

*IPSec configuration from pfSense*

[image: IPSec Interface Firewall]

*The firewall rules on pfSense for the IPSec interface*

[image: IPSec WAN Firewall]

*The firewall ules for IPSec on the WAN of the pfSense*

Comment: It's a lot to ask people to click through 6 screenshots. Can you summarize the important features of them in the question?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman: That's probably because OP doesn't have enough reputation to add images inline, so I helped with that. Sometimes screenshots may reveal something that the person asking doesn't consider relevant while it actually is.